# can't create \footnote because of math

Tags: footnotes

I have this piece in the document:

```
Affymetrix-anotation-file\footnote{HG-U133_Plus_2.na32.annot.csv}
```

now I get an error because of the "Plus" in the footnote. Obviously Latex thinks, this is an math command. How can I solve this type of error?

thx for help

Comment: `\footnote{HG-U133\_Plus\_2.na32.annot.csv}`

Comment: thx, thats it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be the underscore that leads to error.

You can use `\_` instead of `_`.

`Affymetrix-anotation-file\footnote{HG-U133\_Plus\_2.na32.annot.csv}`

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `\urldef` from the `url` package.

```
\usepackage{url}
\urldef\foo{\url{HG-U133_Plus_2.na32.annot.csv}}
```

Then in the footnote:

```
\footnote{\foo}
```